# Order by Start Time

Tags: sql, time

can someone help me to deal with this? i can't solve it sorry.i used asc but it doesn't work. Using SQL,

Column Name : StartTime

```
7:30 PM

*6:30 PM

*10:00 AM

*09:00 AM

*08:00 AM

*05:30 PM
```

what i want is this

```
*08:00 AM

*09:00 AM

*10:00 AM

*05:30 PM

*6:30 PM

*7:30 PM
```

I try :

```
SELECT * 
from tblAppointment 
where date=FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM dd, yyyy') ORDER BY StartTime asc
```

Comment: show your code  ..

Comment: need to convert to `datetime` first

Comment: Sorry sir, here it is. 
`SELECT * from tblAppointment where date=FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM dd, yyyy') ORDER BY StartTime asc`

Comment: Which dbms you are using ?.Like SQLServer/Oracle/Mysql....

Comment: Your query is non-standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: It looks like you've defined `StartTime` as some *string* type rather than a more appropriate one. If you DB has a dedicated `time` datatype, that *could* be used. More appropriate would probably be to stop splitting `date` and `StartTime` into separate columns, if they in fact both relate to a single instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Run This Query This Will Definitely Work If You Are Using SQLServer...**

```
SELECT * from tblAppointment Order by CAST([ColumnName] as datetime);
```